# Function that filters what is shown using p5 and Javascript

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

new to javascript programming here.  I'm using p5.js (and its p5.dom library) to create a bar chart visualization.

I have a dataset that lists people's names, heights, and the states they went to school in.  Here is a partial snippet of it:

```
var height = [{name:"A",height:1,school:"FL"},
{name:"B",height:5,school:"MI"},
{name:"C",height:2,school:"MI"},
{name:"D",height:5,school:"CA"},
{name:"E",height:4,school:"FL"},
{name:"F",height:3,school:"MA"}];
```

I've also created a way to create a bar chart based on the height of each individual, as well as buttons for each school (to be explained further below):

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(300,150);
  fill_color = color(125,125,125);

  h1 = createElement('h1', '');

  fl_button = createButton("FL", "FL");
  fl_button.mousePressed(filterschool);
  mi_button = createButton("MI", "MI");
  mi_button.mousePressed(filterschool);
  ca_button = createButton("CA", "CA");
  ca_button.mousePressed(filterschool);
  ma_button = createButton("MA", "MA");
  ma_button.mousePressed(filterschool);
  reset_button = createButton("reset", "reset");

}

function draw() {
  var idx = -1; 
  for (idx in height) {
    var heading = height[idx].name;
    var val = height[idx].height;

    //Bars
    fill(fill_color);
    stroke();
    rect(idx*15, 100, 10, -val*10);

    //Names
    fill(fill_color);
    noStroke();
    text(heading, idx*15+2, 115);
    }
}
```

Now, what I'd like to do is make it possible to filter what is seen based on the the school that each person attends.  For example, if I click the "FL" button, I want to see only the bars pertaining to those students whose school value is "FL".  I started writing a function to do this:

```
function filterschool(e) {
    alert(e.srcElement.value)
    if (value == "MI") {
        //create a new variable? not sure
    }
}
```

but I'm not sure how to properly set this up.

One attempt I made was to change `function filterschool(e)` to create a new variable:

```
function filterschool(e) {
    alert(e.srcElement.value)
    if (value == "MG") {
        school == value
    }
}
```

and then reference that new variable in`function draw()`:

```
if (height[idx].school == value) {
        fill(fill_color);
        stroke();
        rect(idx*15, 100, 10, -val*10);

    //Names
        fill(fill_color);
        noStroke();
        text(heading, idx*15+2, 115);
        }
```

but I wasn't sure how to define `value` in the `function setup()` to accept all school locations at the outset (before any button is pressed).  Also, even if that worked, I'm not sure this whole approach would be correct anyway.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're close! It's a little hard to tell since you pasted only snippets of half-working code, but it looks like what you have should basically work as long as you modify your `filterschool` callback like this:

```
function filterschool(e) {
  value = e.srcElement.value;
}
```

`=` will assign the button's value to the variable `value`, which you can reference in your draw function (just like in the last code block that you pasted).

Depending on what you're going for, you will probably also need to add a case that shows all bars when `!value`. It would be easier to implement the reset button this way if you set its value to `""`. (You could also just leave the reset button value as it is, of course, and check for `value == "reset"` instead - whatever floats your boat.) Hope it helps!